# GFCI breaker to use in an old Challenger panel with Type C breakers

Tags: circuit-breaker, gfci

I am trying to determine what GFCI breaker to use for a 20A MWBC in an old Challenger panel that requires Eaton Cutler-Hammer BR breaker replacements. I have found at least three models that appear to be potential fits: [GFTCB220](https://www.ebay.com/itm/254623083032?hash=item3b48b7ea18:g:J-UAAOSwY3Ve4qH2), [GFTCB220CS](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Eaton-Type-BR-20-Amp-2-Pole-GFCI-Circuit-Breaker/999977474) and [GFCB220](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002SALDDS). Is either one of these good or do I need to get a specific one? I do not currently have any Challenger GFCI breaker on my panel, so I can't look for a fit based on the model replaced. Here is a photo of my panel label if it helps
[image]
A quick comparison of physical dimensions with the non-GFCI breaker BR220 does not seem to give me much of a clue either
[image: Size comparison]

Comment: They all should be 2" wide. It appears your sources have an inconsistent definition of which one is "width". By the way, all BR breakers are cross-listed type C or type A.  So they *actually are* type C breakers. (or type A if tandem/quad).

Answer (score 7):

### You want the GF*T*CB220

While all three breakers are BR GFCIs, and thus cross-listed to fit your panel, the GFCB220 is an obsolete part number due to the last edition of UL 943 introducing an automatic self-test requirement for GFCIs.  In response to this, Eaton introduced an updated design under the GFTCB part number prefix, so that's what you want; the CS suffix simply stands for a retail clamshell package, though, so that's irrelevant.